# How to show message in if condition in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr class="rowtab" ng-repeat="x in ads |filter: {'ad_type': '' + 1, 'title' :  '' + searchquery, 'categories': {name:''+ catName} } | orderBy: 'ad_type' " ng-  click="adImage(x.title,x.image,x.image_path,x.id)">
    <td >{{x.title}}</td><td class="forbutton"><button class="button icon ion- chevron-right button-clear"></button></td>
</tr>
```

I have this code that display records after filtering the data.I want to show a message if data is empty after filtering.

How should I use ng-if in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<tr class="rowtab" ng-repeat="x in filterd= (ads |filter: {'ad_type': '' + 1, 'title' :  '' + searchquery, 'categories': {name:''+ catName} }) | orderBy: 'ad_type' " ng-  click="adImage(x.title,x.image,x.image_path,x.id)">
    <td >{{x.title}}</td><td class="forbutton"><button class="button icon ion- chevron-right button-clear"></button></td>
</tr>
```

And

```
<div ng-if="filterd.length==0">message</div>
```

Comment: Glad that it helped :)